# skipWaiting not working in Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, workbox

As part of writing ServiceWorker code in `typescript`, I am attaching install handler and then calling `skipWaiting` inside it:

```
self.addEventListener('install', this.onInstall);

protected onInstall() {
    console.log('onInstall called');
    workbox.skipWaiting();
}
```

With this, new ServiceWorker is still in waiting state and skipWaiting doesn't seem to be working. onInstall handler gets called perfectly fine.

**Is typescript implementation artifact causing problem here? Like I should write something like this?**

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    self.skipWaiting();
});
```

**Or self.skipWaiting() doesn't work the same way as workbox.skipWaiting()?**
Interestingly, moving `workbox.skipWaiting()` to ctor where install handler is being attached fixes the issue.

Comment: Does it help you if you inspect the compiled results of the Typescript version? How does that look like?